# How to escape colon in JSON response field in postman test scripts

Tags: javascript, json, postman, escaping

I'm writing a postman test script using the JSON response for a request, and one of the field name is named like `aaa:bbb`. How do I use this field in the test script? When I try using it as it is, I get a Syntax error.

My script is just trying to print the field value:

```
let res = pm.response.json();
res.results.forEach((e) => {
    console.log(e.aaa:bbb);
})
```

I tried all of the following but they do not work:

`e.'aaa:bbb'`

`e."aaa:bbb"`

`e.aaa\:bbb`

`e.jsonValue['aaa:bbb']`

What is the correct escape character or the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't have too much experience with postman but have you tried `e['aaa:bbb']`.